# How to change the Y and X in canvasJS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, canvasjs

I am trying to use the CanvasJS charts as part of my website.

I am using Ajax to retrieve a number from my SQL Database, I want to assign this number to a column in the CanvasJS.

This only displays an empty graph without values.
BUT If I change 'result' to any number - it works fine.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(usersreport).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'js/return.php',
            data: 'id=usersreport',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "theme2",//theme1
        title:{
            text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"              
        },
        animationEnabled: true,   // change to true
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "Active",  y: result  },
                { label: "Inctive",  y: 0  },

            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();


            },
        });
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
        $conn = mysql_connect('156.166.210.100', 'gfgf', 'gfgdgg' or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
        mysql_select_db('gfdgdfgfd') or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
    $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']); // Set email variable
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,roll FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
?>
<?php

$query = sprintf("SELECT count(*) as c FROM users"); 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($res[c]);


mysql_free_result($result);
?>
<?php   
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Please help

Comment: Json, check the type of result, CanvasJS accept y value in number format. If it is string parsing it to number should work fine.

Comment: Hi Sanjoy 
I am returning a Json file - Should I change the format of the return type?

Comment: No, you can parse the the assigning y value (result) to a number.

It would be helpful to understand the problem if you can share sample of your JSON data format.

Comment: Thank you, you were right - managed to solve it.